# Apache Passenger can't find gem

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, phusion-passenger, ubuntu-10.04

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and I've transferred over some sites built in Sinatra. I've set up Phusion passenger, but when I visit the sites I'm getting a Passenger LoadError claiming that passenger has 'no such file to load -- sinatra' yet when I run gem list or sudo gem list, I clearly see sinatra listed. Why can't passenger find this gem?

My sudo gem env output looks like this

> **RubyGems Environment:**
>     - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
>     - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [x86_64-linux]
>     - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>     - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
>     - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
>     - **RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:**
>       - ruby
>       - x86_64-linux
>     - **GEM PATHS:**
>        - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>        - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
>     - **GEM CONFIGURATION:**
>        - :update_sources => true
>        - :verbose => true
>        - :benchmark => false
>        - :backtrace => false
>        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>     - **REMOTE SOURCES:**
>        - http://gems.rubyforge.org/

running 'sudo ruby -v' I see the following:
`ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01`

Is that correct, or should the two ruby versions match up correctly, displaying REE in both?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your `PassengerRuby` ? It should be `/usr/local/bin/ruby` in this case

Comment: Check absolute path with `type ruby` if it says `/usr/local/bin/ruby` then it is correct. Check also `type gem` to be sure that you are using `/usr/local/bin/gem` (from Ruby EE)

Comment: @CasualCoder when I do `type ruby` if says `/usr/local/bin/ruby` and `type gem` says `/usr/local/bin/gem` it says both are hashed. How do I check PassengerRuby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Passenger module configuration files. In my case

content of `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load`:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger2.2.5/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

content of `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5
  PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

`PassengerRuby` is telling module what ruby interpreter to use.

Comment: Thanks Casual Coder, looks like my passenger.conf isn't set up correctly. It looks like the following:  
`<IfModule mod_passenger.c>  
  PassengerRoot /usr  
  PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby  
</IfModule>`

They should both be set-up using the variables we found by running type ruby, right?

Comment: Works perfectly. Cheers Casual Coder.

Comment: Right. `PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby`

Comment: Glad I was helpful. Cheers.